# sql database data lost between to date

Tags: sql, database

first sorry for my english.

I have a SQL Server database. It has records until 2011-01-30 13:44:15. But after this second it did not save any record until 2011-01-31 15:22:09. I looked at the sql database log file there is not any delete action between 2011-01-30 13:44:15 and 2011-01-31 15:22:09. Nobody delete records. nobody changed server datetime. What could have been ? Can I recover this data? If yes how ?

Comment: If the data isn't there, you cannot recover it.....sorry - with such a question, it's just utterly **impossible** to help. We have **no idea** of your database structures, we don't have access to your server and its settings etc. - you need someone on site to help, I'm afraid...

Comment: 1. The system time had lagged for some reason but then restored after synchronisation (but with such a gap... doubtful, to be honest). 2. If the date/time information is provided by the client's side, then check the system time on the client machine(s).

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the application responsible for saving data was working fine in the first place? are you logging any db errors within your app? if yes check for that

if you are sure data was indeed written to sql server, depending upon your backup options and logging options, you can certainly recover most of your data

Comment: thanks for answer.  i am sure data saved. if data deleted by anyone  i can see this action in database log file  can't i?

(note: any record insert,update,delete in log file between these 2 dates)

:(